# Converting an array and performing a contains

Tags: c#, linq

I am reading some data from a database table. One of the fields in the database "VendorList" returns a comma seperated list of Vendors or just one id.

Ex: "1256,553,674" or "346"

There are a couple things I need to do:

- Convert this string to an int[]
- Perform a "Contains" against an IEnumerable collection.
- Return that collection and assign it to a property.

This code is being called inside of a .Select when creating a new object and "Vendor" is a property on that new object.

Here is my code that I am currently using:

```
Vendors = (m.VendorList.Contains(","))
              ? (from v in vendors
                 where m.VendorList.Split(',')
                                   .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n))
                                   .ToArray()
                                   .Contains(v.VendorID)
                 select v).ToList()
              : (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.VendorList))
                    ? null
                    : (from s in vendors
                       where s.VendorID == int.Parse(m.VendorList)
                       select s).ToList()
```

The code works but it looks very messy and it will be hard to maintain if another developer were to try and refactor this.

I am sort of new to linq, can you provide any tips to clean up this mess?

As you can see I am using two ternary operators. The first one is to detect if its a comma separated list. The second is to detect if the comma separated list even have values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where I'd suggest pulling part of this out of your LINQ statement:

```
var vendorIds = m.VendorList
    .Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n))
    .ToArray();

someObj.Vendors = vendors.Where(v => vendorIds.Contains(v.VendorID));
```

1. This is more readable. By assigning a variable to `vendorIds`, you indicate to future programmers what this variable means. They don't have to fully grok all your LINQ code before they can understand the general intent.
2. This will perform better. In your original code, you are re-parsing the entire vendor list *twice for each value in `vendors`.* This code parses it once, and reuses the data structure for all of your ID checks. (If you have large lists of vendor IDs, you can further improve performance by making `vendorIds` a `HashSet<>`.)

If your input is an empty string, the `RemoveEmptyEntries` part will ensure you end up with an empty list of vendor IDs, and hence no matching Vendors. If your input has only one value without commas, you'll end up with a single ID in the list.

Note that this will not behave exactly like your original code, in that it won't set the value to `null` if given a null or empty `m.VendorList`. I'm guessing that if you take time to think about it, having a null `m.VendorList` is not actually something you expect to happen, and it'd be better to "fail fast" if it ever did happen, rather than be left wondering why your `.Vendors` property ended up `null`. I'm also guessing that if you have an *empty* `.Vendors` property, it will be easier for consuming code to deal with correctly than if they have to check for `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I believe it's equivalent to what you're trying to do.. correct me if I'm wrong.

You could do the following in a single line of code, but I think it's more readable (maintainable) this way.

```
var Vendors = new List<int>();

if (m.VendorList != null)
    Vendors.AddRange(vendors.Where(v => m.VendorList
                                         .Split(',')
                                         .Select(y => Convert.ToInt32(y))
                                         .Contains(v))
                            .Select(v => v));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Vendors = from v in vendors
          let vendorList = from idString in m.Split(',')
                           select int.Parse(idString)
          where vendorList.Contains(v.VendorID)
          select v;
```

There is no need to check for the presence of ",".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string str = "356"; //"1256,553,674";

string[] arr = str.Split(',');

List<int> lst = new List<int>();

foreach (string s in arr)
{
    lst.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
}
```

List will contain all numbers in your string

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "1256,553,674";

IEnumerable<int> array = str.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```